# Python testunit: how to test object's attributes ( class data attribute) without assuming a particular name?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am required to write a unittest for a python class without assuming a particular name for class data attribute.
how can I write a test unit for a class not knowing what are the name of the data attributes? for instance I created a creditcard class and I wrote these two test function to create an object and initialize the data attribute before testing any of the class methods. Then I was able to test all other methods in the class.

```
    def setUp(self):
    self._balance = 0
    self._credit_limit = 1200
    self._interest_rate = 0.07
    self._credit = CreditCard(self._balance, self._credit_limit, self._interest_rate)

def test_creditcard_initialized_correctly(self):
    self.assertEqual(self._credit.get_balance(), self._balance)
    self.assertEqual(self._credit.get_creditlimit(), self._credit_limit)
    self.assertEqual(self._credit.get_interest_rate(), self._interest_rate)
```

I guess my question is: how can I test a class methods without knowing the data attributes name? I appreciate any clue. Thanks

Comment: Initialize the object in the test, not the setup. Then use the initialization values to test the `get_x` methods. e.g. `cc = CreditCard(1,2,3); self.assertEqual(cc.get_balance(), 1)` That way you are not relying on the non-public attribute name (`_balance`) for example..

Comment: Your test already does not assume any names of the attributes. The point is that you test accesses object using its external api that is functions like `get_balance` instead of attribute directly `_balance` and that's already what you have.

Comment: Thanks. I had the setUp function which was resting the values of data attribute each time I construct the object (using the data attribute names, directly).